# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: Stumbleupon Share Count - json

Tags: json, wordpress, cross-domain

I want to show share counts from StumbleUpon on my website. **Its work great with Facebook** but **with StumbleUpon I am getting following error:**

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=http://localhost/wordpress/?p=1118.
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

```
<script>
        $.ajax({  
            url: 'http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>', 
             crossDomain: true,
            success: function(data){
            var count = data[0]['count'];
            $("#dd").html(count);
            alert(data);
            $.ajax
                                        ({
                                          type: "POST",
                                          //cache: false,
                                          url: "post.php",

                                          data: { stats: count, paralink:'<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>', social:'2' },
                                          success: function(data) {

                                          },
                                          dataType: 'json'
                                        });  
        } });
    </script>
```

I am using WordPress...

Please Help Me!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I ended up on the solution, i download the extension on google chrome 
Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *
and refresh the page it works for me

Comment: I want to run that script using server cron tab... can you tell me how to unable it for all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer... 
We can use crossOrigin: true to allow cross origin

Here is the working code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="response"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/js/jquery.ajax-cross-origin.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                crossOrigin: true,
                url: "http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=http://www.google.com",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#response").html(data);
                }
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```